# Meta tag synonym proposal: [flag-history] -> [flagging-summary]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, meta, synonym-request

Suggest Meta tag [flag-history](/questions/tagged/flag-history) (5 questions tagged as of now) to be a synonym of [flagging-summary](/questions/tagged/flagging-summary) (24 questions tagged as of now).

---

Given low amount of questions tagged with *flag-history* I was also thinking about retagging these. However on a further thought I preferred it to stay as synonym because "history" seems to carry an important bit of semantics that feels missing in *flagging-summary*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just suggested it.

Up to others to vote for it and a moderator to approve it.

Answer (score 0):

As the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) implies, this request was completed on January 18, 2012. You can see the results on the [Tag Synonyms page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

[image: flag-history <- flagging-summary]

Comment: Please stop bumping old posts to the [home page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=active) with trivial edits and pointless answers (like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295595/230261), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295593/230261), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153016/add-ie7-as-a-synonym-for-internet-explorer-7-on-meta), and in general.

Comment: FYI, the question was already tagged [`status-completed`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) years ago.