# Add [ie7] as a synonym for [internet-explorer-7] on Meta

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, meta, synonym-request

Meta includes both [ie7](/questions/tagged/ie7) and [internet-explorer-7](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-7) and the former should be synonimized to the latter.  IE6 doesn't have the same problem, everyone just calls it "IE6".  IE8 and IE9 have already been similarly synonimized, 7 just slipped through the cracks.

Comment: @animuson: do the same with [id6] ([it6] to [internet-explorer-6])

Comment: @hims056 Done, might take a few minutes to recache.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer so it doesn't pollute search results.

Answer (score -1):

As the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag implies, this request was completed on July 23, 2013. You can see the results on the [Tag Synonyms page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

[image: internet-explorer-7 <- ie7]

Comment: Yes ... that's why the [tag:status-completed] tag was added to the question three years ago :-)