# Tag synonym proposal: [original-author] -> [original-poster]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, meta, synonym-request

Suggest to make tag [original-author](/questions/tagged/original-author) (18 questions tagged as of now) to be a synonym of [original-poster](/questions/tagged/original-poster) (9 questions).

---

Preference for master tag, even though it has less questions, is because I believe it is used more (it even has an [entry in the SE glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146513/165773)).

<sub>Given low amount of questions involved I was also thinking about retagging. However per [discussion in Tavern chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3721018#3721018) I preferred to make a synonym request.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag implies, this request was completed on July 22, 2015. You can see the results on the [Tag Synonyms page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

[image: original poster <- original author]